# Making algorithm2e environments "overlay aware" in beamer

Tags: beamer, numbering, algorithm2e

What is the right away to make algorithms overlay aware in beamer?

When using algorithm2e in a beamer presentation, an algorithm on a frame with overlays can get more than one number.

For example, this code produces two slides, on which the same algorithm gets two different numbers.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[boxruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}  

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{my algorithm}
  \begin{algorithm}[H] \caption{my algorithm}
    do this\;
    then do that\;
  \end{algorithm}

  \pause 

  Some explanations.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The issue appears to be that the algorithm environment is not "overlay aware". I tried using

```
\resetcountonoverlays{algorithm}
```

but that just stopped the file from compiling entirely.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The right counter is `algocf` and not `algorithm`. Also you have to use `\resetcounteronoverlays` instead of `\resetcountonoverlays` since `algocf` is defined as

```
\newcounter{algocf}
```

In other words, adding the following line in your preamble

```
\resetcounteronoverlays{algocf}
```

solves the issue.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[boxruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\resetcounteronoverlays{algocf}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{my algorithm}
  \begin{algorithm}[H] \caption{my algorithm}
    do this\;
    then do that\;
  \end{algorithm}

  \pause

  Some explanations.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]
[image]